# implement a scheduler in spring

Tags: java, spring, timer, scheduled-tasks

A project requires the following scenario to happen:

`class A` has some objects(dynamically created) which it generates along with a `time interval` associated with each object. This class needs the generated object after this `time interval` only. I need to implement a mechanism which provides the class with the objects after it's associated `time interval`. It may also, sometime, need a particular object before the `time interval` expires.

Here's what I did:

- Looked upon [ConcurrentTaskExecutor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ConcurrentTaskExecutor.html) and [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/package-summary.html) but didn't find it useful because I don't want thousands of thread running each for an object. Also, I don't want to repeat a particular job after a time interval.
- I created a `Thread B` which takes all the object in a queue, has an infinite loop which constantly checks all the object's `time interval` with the current time, and puts back if it's `time interval` has not expired.

  ```
  while (true) {
      timerObject = queue.take();
      if (timerObject.getEndTime() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
         //Do something
          } else {
         queue.put(timerObject);
          }
      try {
          Thread.sleep(10);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  ```

This is not a very efficient implementation itself. It has a logical error associated with it. When the objects are very low in number(like 1 or 2), the objects are not in the queue and whenever I try to remove the object from the queue, it shows `unsuccessful`, because the while loop is having the object all the time. And hence I had to put a `sleep` to avoid that. I don't want to check each and every `time interval` when the queue size grows up to 10K or so.

Is there any simple and efficient way to achieve the solution. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ConcurrentTaskScheduler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ConcurrentTaskScheduler.html), or implement something like it using [DelayQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html).
You can use it with spring's Concurrent framework (for example subclassing [ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean.html)) or with core java Executors.